# How to reverse this mathematical formula

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am using the following function to compute a "Y" value from a Latitude

```
var LAT = latitude

// convert Lat to Radians
var latRad = LAT * Math.PI / 180;

var merc = Math.log(Math.tan((Math.PI / 4) + (latRad / 2)));

// compute to y value
var y = (8192 / 2) - (8192 * merc / (2 * Math.PI));
```

I need to be able to reverse this formula to compute the variable LAT only knowing the value for the variable y

Comment: I haven't tried much. I'm not very fluent with this type of math. I have no idea what Math.tan or Math.log are. I am coding a Java app and was pointed to this method for the lat to y transformation by someone much smarter than myself.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wolfram Alpha, with $x=\text{LAT}$....

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your time and knowledge, however the above result is formatted as a math equation, and I am familiar with doing math in java. I have no idea how to apply the answer in said format, but I truly appreciate the response. I do understand the input interpretation though

Comment: No problem.  Somebody else might come along and be able to give you a more straightforward equation.

Answer (score 0):

It's all a matter of doing things backwards. Let's start from your snippet:

```
var LAT = latitude

// convert Lat to Radians
var latRad = LAT * Math.PI / 180;

var merc = Math.log(Math.tan((Math.PI / 4) + (latRad / 2)));

// compute to y value
var y = (8192 / 2) - (8192 * merc / (2 * Math.PI));
```

Reverse the order of the lines:

```
// compute to y value
var y = (8192 / 2) - (8192 * merc / (2 * Math.PI));
var merc = Math.log(Math.tan((Math.PI / 4) + (latRad / 2)));
// convert Lat to Radians
var latRad = LAT * Math.PI / 180;
```

and peel things off gradually. Let's do the first line explicitly:

```
y = (8192 / 2) - (8192 * merc / (2 * Math.PI));

(8192 * merc / (2 * Math.PI)) = (8192 / 2) - y;
8192 * merc = ((8192 / 2) - y) * (2 * Math.PI);
var merc = ((8192 / 2) - y) * (2 * Math.PI) / 8192;
```

I'll skip the details for the second line, but you should end up with

```
var latRad = 2 * Math.atan(Math.exp(merc)) - Math.PI / 2
```

and finally,

```
var LAT = latrad * 180 / Math.PI;
```

thus:

```
var merc = ((8192 / 2) - y) * (2 * Math.PI) / 8192;
var latRad = 2 * Math.atan(Math.exp(merc)) - Math.PI / 2
var LAT = latrad * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Since $8192/2=4096$, your code could stand to be simplified a bit... ;)

Comment: 8192 is a variable that can change, I just included 8192 to simplify the question.